# Individual File update in jar fails

Tags: java, java-8, jar

I am following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729647/update-a-file-inside-a-jar-in-a-specific-directory-with-jar-command) to update a file content inside the jar
And run following command

```
jar tvf <jarfileName>
```

and then

```
jar xvf <FullFilePath>
```

and at last

```
jar vuf <FolderName>/
```

So what exactly happening here , in jar i have structure like this

```
Foo.jar (root directory)
/
|->/folder1
|
|->/folder2
|
|->/foo
    |
    |-->/bar
         |
         |---->/baz
               |
               |------>file1
               |------>file2
               |------>file3
               |------>file..N
```

After running above commands ,jar folder Structure change like this

```
Foo.jar (root directory)
/
|
|->/foo
    |
    |-->/bar
         |
         |---->/baz
               |
               |------>file1
```

It is deleting everything and update with only file and folder structure which was extracted.

Comment: I doubt that `jar vuf <FolderName>/` does anything useful when not even the jar file name has been given. For questions like this, exactness is important.

Comment: I have to update a individual file inside the jar file .

Comment: That’s understood.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not limited to using `jar` command only, I would offer as one of the solutions to use any zip utils because `jar` file is a plain old `zip` archive.

You can unpack it to the folder, replace all required files and pack it back again.

You can do it with internal java zip support or use other tools to work with zip files from java like [zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm).

***P.S.** [zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm) is written by me*