# Is it possible to modify a .jar file without create a whole new one?

Tags: java

I am working on a Java application. Essentially, it picks a `.jar` file and then inserts some files into it.

I am using the answer from [Updating .JAR's contents from code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7548900/555690). However, it is slow because it is literally make a brand new file and manually copying all the files (including the old ones) into it!

I find this strange. Is it not possible to modify a `.jar` file without create a whole new one?

Comment: You can use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to add and delete files from a JAR. It is just a ZIP file.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without external libraries

Comment: jar files are just archives. You can extract and create then with the same syntax as tar. jar -xvf , jar -cvf etc..

Comment: @Chloe: using Java...

Answer (score 0):

No. It's a ZIP file, and these are sequential in nature. All the tools that update them do so by copying, and you have to do the same.

Comment: Not true: http://superuser.com/questions/647674/is-there-a-way-to-edit-files-inside-of-a-zip-file-without-explicitly-extracting

Comment: @DonaldW That question isn't even relevant: it's about editing single files rather than adding new ones, which is what this one is about. And I don't see anything there that contradicts this answer, just the use of tools, which behave as I've described above.

Comment: The statement that 'all tools that update them do so by copying is simly not true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java

Comment: @DonaldW I don't see any actual evidence there, other than several statements that agree with me and give cogent reasons such as the directory being at the end of the file. You don't know how these virtualization APIs work under the hood. Re editing individual files you also need to think about the CRC, which is in the directory.

Comment: I have managed to update a .JAR file without copying it or recreating its contents. I used Java's Zip File System: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html