# Write/Read xml files within my executable jar

Tags: java, xml

I was wondering if there is a way for me to write to an xml file within my executable jar? 
You see, I want it so I can create new xml files whilst running the jar and be able to read it. 
I tried,

File result = new File("[package name within my project]/staff.xml);

but it returns null because staff.xml is not in that package yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a new file to a Jar during runtime, see this question [Java: Add Class to Jar archive at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110701/java-add-class-to-jar-archive-at-runtime).

As for reading the files you definitely can. You will need to use the `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` methods.

Example

```
String path = "/package/name/within/my/project/staff.xml";
File result = new File(this.getClass().getResource(path).getFile());
```